# "This paper has been submitted/published in" stamp on arxiv

Tags: arxiv, license

I am in the process of submitting a paper on arxiv and I would like to know if there is anyone who knows if the part in gray in the following picture gets automatically added on the paper or I should take care of it.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gray part is added by the publisher (IEEE) on the early access version of the manuscript, once accepted.

Note that you may not be allowed to submit such a version to arXiv, see [this question and the accepted answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145690/20058).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However, I am talking about (I should have mentioned it) of a IEEE conference paper. The paper has been accepted but it will appear in the proceedings (maybe) in 3 months or so. Therefore I would like to upload it on arxiv. Everyone in my community (robotics) does it, this is why I was thinking that it is allowed (I know that it is not the best reason ;) )

Comment: @desmond13 You should check the so-called "author rights" for those proceedings. In general, IEEE is quite strict on what can be put on preprint repositories.

Comment: This is what I found: 
https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/become-an-ieee-journal-author/publishing-ethics/guidelines-and-policies/policy-posting-your-journal-article/

Since mine is an accepted article, it seems that I can put it on arxiv

Comment: @desmond13 Good! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

arXiv does not add anything like this automatically.

Comment: It adds its own watermark in the left border of the first page, though. The watermark is a link to the Arxiv page of the preprint, and does not mention external journals.

Answer (score 2):

No, Arxiv only adds its own watermark on the left side of the first page.

Do note, though, that among the article's metadata on Arxiv there is a "journal ref" field where you can specify in which journal your preprint was published. Once you log into your account, next to your list of Arxiv articles you will see a "journal ref" icon.

This is the recommended way to add this information, since it gets added to the database and is not just inside the pdf in a difficult-to-parse text format.